# How to (best) align this list?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

The desired result:
[image]

My attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage{tablists}
\usepackage{multicol}

\title{Extension Multiplication of Algebra}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\maketitle

\renewcommand\tabenumsep{\hskip3em}

\section*{Exercise 1}


1 \quad Expand the brackets in these expressions.
\begin{tabenum}[a)]
\item $2(a+5)$
\item $4(b+3)$
\item $5(d+7)$
\item $4(x+8)$ \\
\item $6(5-r)$
\item $4(b-4)$
\item $8(y-5)$
\item $3(x+y)$ \\
\item $9(d-9)$
\item $3(x+12)$
\item $12(t-r)$
\item $7(x-y)$
\end{tabenum}


2 \quad Expand the brackets in these expressions.
\begin{tabenum}[a)]
\item $3(2n-6m)$
\item $5(4u+8v)$
\item $7(5n-6m)$
\item $3(u+8v)$ \\
\item $4(4x-7y)$
\item $3(2p-11q)$
\item $8(2s-12t)$
\item $6(4x+5y)$
\end{tabenum}

\section*{Exercise 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the easiest way to align this?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean the vertical gap? Try it with `\vspace{-3mm}` before the `\begin{tabenum}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We fight with a tag team → `enumitem` and `tasks`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}

\NewTasks[
counter-format={tsk[a])},
label-format=\bfseries,
label-width=1.5em,
label-align=left,    %% or right as you wish
label-offset=0.5em,
item-indent=2em,
after-item-skip=0pt,
after-skip=-0.5\baselineskip,,
before-skip=-0.5\baselineskip,,
resume=true   %% comment this for not to resume
]{problems}[\item](4)    %% (4) here makes all of them in 4 columns


\title{Extension Multiplication of Algebra}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Exercise 1}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\arabic*,leftmargin=*]
\item Expand the brackets in these expressions.
\begin{problems}%(3) %% (3) here makes this 3 column.
\item $2(a+5)$
\item $4(b+3)$
\item $5(d+7)$
\item $4(x+8)$ 
\item $6(5-r)$
\item $4(b-4)$
\item $8(y-5)$
\item $3(x+y)$ 
\item $9(d-9)$
\item $3(x+12)$
\item $12(t-r)$
\item $7(x-y)$
\end{problems}
%
\item Expand the brackets in these expressions.
\begin{problems}%(4)
\item $3(2n-6m)$
\item $5(4u+8v)$
\item $7(5n-6m)$
\item $3(u+8v)$ 
\item $4(4x-7y)$
\item $3(2p-11q)$
\item $8(2s-12t)$
\item $6(4x+5y)$
\end{problems}
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Exercise 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And we win `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

After fighting with `tablists`, I'd recommend using a basic `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\title{Extension Multiplication of Algebra}
\date{}
\author{}

%establish indent
\newlength{\tabidnt}
\settowidth{\tabidnt}{1 \quad}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

%setup "enumerator" counter and format
\newcounter{ctabitem}
\renewcommand{\thectabitem}{\alph{ctabitem})}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{%
    \stepcounter{ctabitem}%
    \textbf{\thectabitem}}

%column type for "enumerator" and contents
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\tabitem}p{1.7em}<{}>{\ $}p{8em}<{$}}   

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\maketitle

\section*{Exercise 1}
1 \quad Expand the brackets in these expressions.\par
\hspace{\tabidnt}\begin{tabular}{AAAA}
&2(a+5)&
&4(b+3)&
&5(d+7)&
&4(x+8)\\
&6(5-r)&
&4(b-4)&
&8(y-5)&
&3(x+y)\\
&9(d-9)&
&3(x+12)&
&12(t-r)&
&7(x-y)\\
&3(x+12)&
&12(t-r)&
&7(x-y)&
&11(4-b)
\end{tabular}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

2 \quad Expand the brackets in these expressions.\par
\setcounter{ctabitem}{0}%restart the "enumeration" at a.
\hspace{\tabidnt}\begin{tabular}{AAAA}
&3(2n-6m)&
&5(4u+8v)&
&7(5n-6m)&
&3(u+8v)\\
&4(4x-7y)&
&3(2p-11q)&
&8(2s-12t)&
&6(4x+5y)
\end{tabular}

\section*{Exercise 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]